# iron-media-query doesn't work - Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new to Polymer (1.0).

My `<iron-media-query>` element is not working. No errors in the console but it does not display anything.

Some improvements would be awesome! I'm trying to get it up and running since 2 hours. :)

Thanks in advance

Ron

```
<!-- Works correctly -->
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-media-query/iron-media-query.html">

<dom-module id="custom-element">

  <style>
    // Styles here
  </style>

  <template>

    <iron-media-query query="{{query}}" queryMatches="{{smallScreen}}"></iron-media-query>

    <template if="{{smallScreen}}">
      <strong>Small Screen</strong>
    </template>

    <template if="{{!smallScreen}}">
      <strong>Big Screen</strong>
    </template>

  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'custom-element',

    properties: {
      query: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      }
    }

  });

</script>

<custom-element query="(max-width:400px)"></custom-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `queryMatches="{{}}"` to `query-matches="{{}}"`.

Comment: I also have to add `is="dom-if"` to template tag. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you also asked about optmizations:

Since you don't have a massive difference in the data between `SmallScreen` and not, so:

```html
<strong>[[screenType]] Screen</strong>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'custom-element',
        properties: {
            query: {
                type: String,
                notify: true
            },
            screenType: {type: String, computed: '_computeScreenType(smallScreen)'}
        },
        _computeScreenType: (t)=>{return t?"Small":"Big"}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's trivial, but gives you a readable property, and avoids dom-if's.